# Do I need to calculate proposal probability using random walk on exponential space?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics

I know I can use symmetric random walk to avoid computing the proposal probability.

However, I'm not sure if doing symmetric random walk on transformed space should also cancel the proposal probability as well.

So I did experiment to see if this is true.

First I did the random walk on exponential space then I got the first figure below.

Second I did standard random walk. Then I get a distribution that is closer to the true distribution, but the KS test is still not passing. The result is shown in the second figure.

[image]
[image]

Just to be explicit about how I did the test, the code in Python is as below.

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

def test_random_walk_on_exp_space():
    LB = 0.2
    UB = 1.5
    step_size = (np.exp(-LB) - np.exp(-UB)) / 5
    I = 10000
    x = (UB - LB) / 2
    x_samples = []
    x_compares = []
    for i in range(I):
        exp_ne_x_new = \
            np.minimum(np.maximum(np.exp(-x), np.exp(-UB) + step_size), np.exp(-LB) - step_size) + \
                np.random.uniform(-step_size, step_size)
        if np.log(np.random.uniform()) < stats.norm.logpdf(-np.log(exp_ne_x_new)) - stats.norm.logpdf(x):
            x = -np.log(exp_ne_x_new)
        x_samples.append(x)

        y = stats.norm.rvs()
        while y > UB or y < LB:
            y = stats.norm.rvs()
        x_compares.append(y)
    print(stats.ks_2samp(x_samples, x_compares)[1])
    plt.hist(x_samples, alpha=0.5, label="x_samples")
    plt.hist(x_compares, alpha=0.5, label="x_compares")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


def test_random_walk():
    LB = 0.2
    UB = 1.5
    step_size = (UB - LB) / 30
    I = 1000
    x = (UB - LB) / 2
    x_samples = []
    x_compares = []
    for i in range(I):
        x_new = \
            np.minimum(np.maximum(x, LB + step_size), UB - step_size) + \
                np.random.uniform(-step_size, step_size)
        if np.log(np.random.uniform()) < stats.norm.logpdf(x_new) - stats.norm.logpdf(x):
            x = x_new
        x_samples.append(x)

        y = stats.norm.rvs()
        while y > UB or y < LB:
            y = stats.norm.rvs()
        x_compares.append(y)
    print(stats.ks_2samp(x_samples, x_compares)[1])
    plt.hist(x_samples, alpha=0.5, label="x_samples")
    plt.hist(x_compares, alpha=0.5, label="x_compares")
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.random.seed(0)
    test_random_walk_on_exp_space()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: 1. Your post lacks a clear question. 2. It may be worth writing what you believe your code is doing; just posting code conflates errors of understanding and errors of implementation, which can make it harder to identify the problem

Comment: @Glen_b edited..

Comment: @Glen_b is it better?